# Distance formula in kinematics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I've always seen it $d = v_i t + \frac{1}{2} at^2$
However, I also saw it as $d= d_i + v_i t + \frac{1}{2} at^2$ where $d_i$ = initial position. This was applied to 2D kinematics. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Hint to the question (v4) : _position,_ _displacement,_ and _distance_ are in general different physical quantities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're first equation $$d = V_i t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$ is saying that the total distance is the initial velocity, times time, plus one half times the acceleration times time squared

Now the only difference between this and the second equation is obviously the $d_i$. Basically, this is a more complete kinematic description of your object, the reason being that with this equation we can choose the origin to be *anywhere*. The first equation assumes your object starts at the origin. The second equation takes into account the fact that your object could actually be initially displaced from the origin of interest a certain distance $d_i$, so in the final calculation of the final distance, we must take into account this offset from our measured origin.

Comment: Probably worth calling the first equation displacement and the second equation position.